# How do i get the text inside a with button with clicking on it, with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

i need the result in a html paragraph

`<p id="result">Here the Button Text</p>`

This is the Html part

`<button type="button" id="vteam">i need this text</button>`

This is the JS part

`$(document).on('click', '.vteam', function(event) {}`

Comment: Example `$('#vteam').on('click', function(e) { $(this).text('text here')})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`event.target` refers to the clicked element, so you can get the text inside it like so: `event.target.innerText`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the following:

```
    function changeText() {
        document.getElementById("vteam").innerHTML = "Hello";
}
```

and

```
<p id="vteam" onclick="changeText()">I need this text to change</p>
```

Comment: Put vteam in quotes.  getElementById("vteam")

Comment: i don't know it says null

Comment: Check out my sample  https://jsfiddle.net/xyvkbjap/   it works with your code.

Comment: oh thanks @Grax32  I see, and one advice, add a feature so that it changes based on the current text. That way, something always happens when you click instead of once. You can use if statements but if you have any other method, that's ok. (i am neither a programmer nor so good at programming so you probably know it better)

Answer (score 0):

You can give your inner text as an id to element .and in event handler you can access your inner text by this way:

```
e.target.id
```